# Function is returning before SqlQuery finishes

Tags: javascript, sqlite, async-await

I have a function that has a query that connects to a database and does a basic SELECT query, The query works fine, however the function appears to be returning before the query finishes all of its steps. In this case I have the Hello World Console log and the array is undefined. But if I setTimeout for one second and then log out the "NewArray" it has all the data from the query. So my question is: How do I return this data after the query has finished doing its magic.

```
async function getData() {
    let newArray = []
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('PATHTODB',sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
      }
    });
    let selectQuery = `SELECT * FROM TableName;`
      await db.all(
          `${selectQuery}`,
          (err, row) => {
            console.log(row)
            row.forEach(x => {
              newArray.push(x)
            })
      
          } 
          
        )
        console.log("Hello World", newArray)

  return newArray
}
```

Tried using ASYNC/AWAIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.all(query, callback)` is not an async function to `await`. It's just invoking it's callback asynchronously. Try promisfying it as follows;

```
async function getData() {
    let newArray = []
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('PATHTODB',sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
      }
    });
    let selectQuery = `SELECT * FROM TableName;`,
        row = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => 
                db.all(`${selectQuery}`, (err,row) => err ? reject(err)
                                                          : resolve(row)));
            
    console.log(row);
    row.forEach(x => newArray.push(x));
    console.log("Hello World", newArray);
    return newArray
}
```